# Show a tasks list by clicking on project name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two models Project and Task. Each project has many tasks.

there is a list of projects on project index page.

and i want, when user clicks on project name, list of project's tasks is shown aside from projects list

i try something like that.

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#projects').on('click', 'h2', function(){
    $('#tasks').append("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'tasks/index.html.erb') %>");
  });
});
```

is it correct to change application.js file extansion to js.erb?

**UPDATE**

result of my work
_project.html.erb

```
<%= link_to " #{project.title} tasks list", project_tasks_path(project), :remote => true %>
```

task_controller.rb

```
  def index
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])    
@tasks = @project.tasks
respond_with @tasks
```

end

index.js.erb

```
$('#project-tasks').html("<%= j render :file => 'projects/tasks/_tasks', :locals => { :tasks => @tasks }  %>");
```

_tasks.html.erb

```
<%= render @tasks %>
```

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: I had a question whether I can embed ruby code into the application.js file. thanks to Ramiz Raja, Vezu, sanny Sin, i understood that i can't . I would like to get advice on how to get the project id in order to get all project tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use rails way to do this. Use ajax call and make js.erb file to update your view.
see this http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to save it as somethingelse.js.erb and not change the application.js

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename application js to something else. Better make new js.erb file and put your code into it